# Como eu crio uma estrutura CRUD com PHP

Tags: php

Quero criar uma comunicação CRUD em PHP, levando informações do painel administrativo para a página principal.
Como um blog, porém, com todos os códigos editáveis.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer criar um blog simples em PHP aonde as informações do blog (como postagens e comentários) estão em um banco de dados. É isso?

Comment: Se você ainda precisa aprender tudo o que disse na [sua outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46430/gostaria-de-uma-apostila-sobre-php-completa-para-criar-um-site-de-compras), as explicações aqui teriam de ser longas demais para o formato deste site. Sugiro que escolha um ponto de partida (dê uma olhada no [Wordpress](http://br.forums.wordpress.org)), e volte aqui com dúvidas mais pontuais.

Comment: Sim, Victtor.
É está estrutura que queria. Se tive-se alguma pronta, para eu ter uma noção e começar a desenvolver.

Comment: Meu site: www.jaguaribeparacristo.com.br

Comment: Eu aderi a uma template interessante, porem não estou encontrando onde edito estas informações. As informações que edito no painel não são capazes de alterar algumas coisas, talvez, tem que ser alterado no html central.

Comment: Você viu o link que coloquei com a documentação do WordPress? E por favor não use a área de respostas mais abaixo para responder aos comentários aqui. Use o link de adicionar comentário.  Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você já ouviu falar sobre [Static Site Generator](https://www.staticgen.com/)?

"Falando de forma resumida, geradores estáticos usam várias funcionalidades que estamos acostumados a utilizar nas linguagens de programação, como includes, loopings, templates, entre outras coisas legais. Mas... gera um HTML, sem banco de dados, sem dependências server-side, tudo é gerado em um HTML puro e simples."

**Fonte:** [felipefialho](http://www.felipefialho.com/blog/2013/geradores-estaticos-breve-explicacao/#.VLEgJyvF9gA)

Eles são perfeitos para construção de blogs ou semelhantes. Eu uso o Jekyll pra gerenciar meu blog. Mas ele é feito em Ruby, já que você usa PHP eu recomendo o [Sculpin](https://sculpin.io/). É muito simples de usar. Olha a [documentação](https://sculpin.io/getstarted/). Em menos de 3 minutos você tem seu conteúdo publicado na web!